# Pseudo chiral centre

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I was reading about stereoisomers and I came across a term pseudo chiral centre.  I looked up on the net for its definition and found a weird formula for calculating no. of isomers if the compound has a pseudo chiral centre.

I can't understand how to deduce the formula and how to do analytically instead of using the formula in case of complex molecules say of more than 3 chiral carbon atoms.

Comment: Suppose you have the following compound,4-Methylhepta-2,5-diene.The central carbon atom-C 4 is  pseudo chiral because it is chiral only when the stereo centers at C2-C3 and C5-C6 are of different configuration other wise it is not chiral

Comment: See the gold book definition of [pseudo-asymmetric carbon atom](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.P04921).

Comment: Yes I saw the definition but how to deduce the formula

Comment: It's something dependent on number of stereocentes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Consider this molecule]

Carbon number 4 is a pseudo chiral center because its chirality depends on the chirality of the second and sixth carbons. For example, if the second carbon is S and the sixth carbon is R, then carbon number 4 can be r or s, but if the chirality of the second and sixth carbons are the same, then carbon number 4 is not the chiral center, because it doesn't have 4 different groups around itself.

Comment: When C2/C6 are of different configurations (R/S), C4 will be stereogenic and achirotopic (r/s). When  C2/C6 are of the same configurations (R/R or S/S), C4 will be chirotopic and non-stereogenic. There is no r/s assignment. See: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/RSrs.html

Answer (score -2):

Pseudoassymetric center is the carbon that show chirality and achirality simultaneously.
The r/s (not R/S) nomenclature of carbon 4 depend on R/S configuration of directly attached carbon atom.
In the given molecule the carbon 4 is attached with constituitionaly same but configurationaly different group so it is a chiral center (note: R configuration  has priority over S configuration). if we imagine it has a plane of symmetry and that make it achiral.

Comment: What is the "given molecule" that you are referring to?

Comment: It is good that (*interpretation* reading your answer) that you discern chirality at the level of an atom, and its neighbours from chirality of the molecule.  The answer would improve if there were illustrations to support the argumentation. But then, if you focus on the lower level, i.e. environment around an atom, it is more than puzzling than atom should simultaneously experience an spatial arrangement *both* chiral and achiral when the leading «a» in «achiral» denotes the *absence* of chirality; the two are mutually exclusive.  Like e.g., is an information *public* .or. *private*.