# In which of the these structures C-3 carbon is not a chiral centre?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

> In which of the these structures C-3 carbon is not a chiral centre?[image]

I think that the answer to the above question should be both (b) and (c) as C-3 is attached to same groups and also they have a plane of symmetry hence making it achiral. But, the answer given to this problem is (d) with the reasoning that only in (d) option configurations of the both the carbon attached to C-3 is same while the configurations of both the carbon attached to C-3 is different in (b) and (c).

Should the configurations of C-2 and C-4 carbons even matter here?

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/RSrs.html

Comment: [This](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139094/pseudo-chiral-centre) question should also help you out.